# Google map for android application doesn't work on the market

Tags: java, android, google-maps

i build an android app using map activity .. when i test the app on my PC the map work fine but when i upload the app to the market all what i have on the map is the pins but no map in background , please please can any body help me ...

Comment: If you want to help us you should definitely add more information like some relevant code (but please don't post masses) etc.

Answer (score 5):

You have to generate the android map key with the keystore you are using to upload the apk to the market.

Here you have all the information you need:

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Hope this helps...